# How to decode subject line

Tags: php, imap

I received an email whose subject line is Last Day Today☛ An Additional 32% Off Your Favourite Brands, but when I looked into it's header subject line looks like -

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Last=20Day=20Today=E2=98=9B=20An=20Additional=2032%=20Off=20Your=20?=
=?utf-8?Q?Favourite=20Brands.?=
```

If I fetch out value of subject using imap_headerinfo() then how could I decode this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try [mb_decode_mimeheader();](http://php.net/mb_decode_mimeheader) This might work for you.

Comment: Thanks Deepak @Dave chen and Naeems solution works as per i need

Answer (score 3):

`imap_mime_header_decode` will work for you, i.e.

```
<?php
$text = "=?utf-8?Q?Last=20Day=20Today=E2=98=9B=20An=20Additional=2032%=20Off=20Your=20?=
=?utf-8?Q?Favourite=20Brands.?=";

$elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
var_dump($elements); //will print array values for you
```

here is more detail [PHP IMAP Header decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try [imap_mime_header_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php):

```
<?php

print_r(imap_mime_header_decode('=?utf-8?Q?Last=20Day=20Today=E2=98=9B=20An=20Additional=2032%=20Off=20Your=20?=
=?utf-8?Q?Favourite=20Brands.?='));
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/vZqh0epc):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charset] => utf-8
            [text] => Last Day Today☛ An Additional 32% Off Your 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charset] => utf-8
            [text] => Favourite Brands.
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir...but i am getting [text] => Last Day Todayâ˜› An Additional 32% Off....How could I remove  special character

Comment: Make sure in your HTML head you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, also make sure you are echoing with `utf8_encode( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use imap_mime_header_decode() on the string.

Answer (score 0):

[iconv_mime_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php) - Decodes a MIME header field